# New settings in the Group Settings API...were these announced?

Tags: google-groups-api, google-admin-settings-api

I noticed some new settings in the Google Group Settings API...were these announced?  Where should we look for such announcements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're referring to spam moderation and include in GAL? No, they weren't announced to my knowledge. Google's getting better at announcing changes but they still slip in updates like this from time to time with no way of knowing till you happen to find it buried in ref. docs.

I suggest tracking the doc pages where possible. I use [ChangeDetection.com](http://www.changedetection.com) to get email notifications when reference docs get updated.

Answer (score 1):

This particular change wasn't announced anywhere except for the updated reference docs. Often changes are posted to the Developer's Blog at http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/, just not for this.